# Index error, can't seem to figure this one out

Tags: python

I am totally lost on what to do with this code. But im getting an error on the line
account.append(BankAccount(lst[0],lst[1],float(lst[2]),float(lst[3].replace('\n',''))))

can anyone help me with how to correct this?
Thank you!

FULL CODE:

class BankAccount: #BankAccount class implementation

```
def __init__(self, ID,PIN,checking,savings):

    self.ID = ID

    self.PIN = PIN

    self.checking = checking

    self.savings = savings

def getID(self):

    return self.ID

def getPIN(self):

    return self.PIN

def getSavings(self):

    return self.savings

def getChecking(self):

    return self.checking

 

def withdraw(self,amount,type): #withdraw method returns False if

    if(type==1):

      #amount is greater than savings balance

      if(self.savings<amount):

         return False

      else: #else deducts amount from savings balance and returns True

         self.savings -= amount

    elif(type==2):

        #amount is greater than savings balance

        if(self.checking<amount):

            return False

        else:

            self.checking -= amount

    return True

def deposit(self,amount,type):

    if(type==1):

        self.savings += amount

    elif(type==2):

        self.checking += amount
```

def main():

```
account = []

n=0

with open("accounts.txt") as file: #reads data from file named accounts.txt

    for line in file: #reads line by line from file

        li = line.split(' ') #splits the line based on ' '

        #creates an object of BankAccount and appends it to account list

        account.append(BankAccount(li[0],li[1],float(li[2]),float(li[3].replace('\n',''))))

        n += 1 #to keep track of number of accounts read from file

userid = input("Enter ID: ")

userpin = input("Enter PIN: ")

i=0

#loops through accounts and performs respective operations

while i<n:

    if(account[i].getID()==userid):

        if(account[i].getPIN()==userpin):

            option = int(input('Enter 1 for withdraw 2 for transfer 3 for balance: '))

            if(option==1):

                type = int(input('Select type 1. Savings 2.checking: '))

                amount = float(input("Enter amount: "))

                if(account[i].withdraw(amount,type)):

                    if(type==1):

                        print(amount,'withdrawn. Closing balance: ',account[i].getSavings())

                    else:

                        print(amount,'withdrwan. Closing balance: ',account[i].getChecking())

                else:

                    print('insufficient funds in your account')

            elif(option==2):

                option = int(input('Enter 1 for within account transfer 2 for other account: '))

                if(option==1): #within account transfer

                    fromto = int(input('Enter 1. transfer from savings to checking 2. transfer from checking to savings: '))

                    amount = float(input('Enter amount: '))

                    if(fromto==1):

                        account[i].withdraw(amount,1)

                        account[i].deposit(amount,2)

                        print('Transfer successful from savings to checking')

                    else:

                        account[i].withdraw(amount,2)

                        account[i].deposit(amount,1)

                        print('Transfer successful from checking to savings')

                else: #other account transfer

                    accID = input('Enter account ID to transfer money: ')

                    j=0

                    while j<n:

                        if(account[j].getID()==accID):

                            break

                        j += 1

                    if(j<n):

                        type = int(input('Select type 1. Savings 2.checking: '))

                        amount = float(input("enter amount: "))

                        account[i].withdraw(amount,type)

                        account[j].deposit(amount,type)

                        print('Transfer successful to account :',account[j].getID())

                        if(type==1):

                            print(amount,'transferred. Your savings balance: ',account[i].getSavings())

                        else:

                            print(amount,'transferred. Your checking balance: ',account[i].getChecking())

                    else:

                        print('Invalid account ID. Transfer of funds terminated.')

            else:

                type = int(input('Select type 1. Savings 2.checking: '))

                if(type==1):

                    print('Your savings balance:',account[i].getSavings())

                else:

                    print('Your checking balance:',account[i].getChecking())

            break

    i += 1

if(i==n): #if i reaches n then it's an invalid login

    print('invalid login')

else: #writes the account details into the file accounts.txt

    file = open('accounts.txt','w')

    j=0

    while j<n:

        file.write(account[j].getID()+' '+account[j].getPIN()+' '+str(account[j].getChecking())+' '+str(account[j].getSavings())+' ')

        j += 1

file.close() #closes file stream

print('Thank you!!')
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a line with less than 4 elements in your `accounts.txt` file (possibly an empty line at the end).